# Angular 4 JS script not working after changing route

Tags: jquery, angular

I try to load a script via angular-cli to sync two divs. When page is loaded for the first time, the script is working fine. Aftter that I change the route via Navigation. When going back to the first page, the script is not working anymore.

Angular CLI:

```
  "scripts": [
    ....
    "assets/scripts/scrollsync.js"
  ]
```

scrollsync.js:

```
$(function() {
  $('#column-item-container').on('scroll', function () {
    $('#row-lead-container').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
  });

  $('#column-item-container').on('scroll', function () {
    $('#column-lead-container').scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
  });
});
```

I try to figure out if the script is still present to set a timeout with 1000ms sending some to console, that works fine. I looks like the binding is not working anymore. 
Some advice to fix this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue probably happening because most of third party library or custom code initialize on document ready event. So that's why it work first time. Once you navigate to another page and come back on same page, angular not reloading page, it just render html part and document ready event not fire.

**Solution**

- Bind event when your page open, not on document ready.
- You can make a directive to bind scroll event, directive will always bind event when dom element bind, it not depend on document ready event.

Comment: Solve it with create a custom typing and call a bind-method in ngOnInit.

Comment: @Kishan Mundha  Am working with angular with php. I tried this method its not working for me. I think my way is wrong. Kindly please explain the steps for directive to bind an event.

Comment: can anyone please tell me the solution?