# How to fully reload an Angular component only when user is logged in?

Tags: javascript, angular

In my Angular project I've got:

- **SignInComponent** -> Handling the login requests
- **DashboardComponent** -> Displayed for all children when user has successfully logged in
- **HomeComponent** -> The actual content/page that will be displayed to the user - A child of 'DashboardComponent'

And it looks like:

```
    export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'login', component: SignInComponent
    },
    {
        path: '', component: DashboardComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
        ],
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    },
    {
        path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'prefix'
    }
]
```

Now the problem that I'm facing, is that when the user is successfully logged in, that it won't reload the component 'DashboardComponent'. And I'm not referring to the routes itself (those are going fine). But there's one needed JS script not loaded which blocks the user from expanding the menu item(s). See below:

[image]

However, when you manually reload the page, it will work. The menu item(s) will expand. See below:

[image]

So, fully reloading the component would do the trick, but I only want that when it's matching with the previous 'route', in this case '/login'. In other words, I would to fully reload the 'DashboardComponent', only when it's not a 'child'. How could I apply this?

Or is there perhaps a better and easier approach?

Answer (score 0):

Here it looks some url match problem because you have defined `path:''` to dashboard also making that path to redirect to login with next routing object in routes array

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'login', component: SignInComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
        ],
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    },
    {
        path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'prefix'
    }
]
```

So change it like above code and try.  This will not make any url confusion and redirection will take place properly

Comment: Thanks, actually I don't want to have '/dashboard', or '/home' in the URL. Dashboard is actually a 'partial' (only the top bar is shown in there). Home contains the actual content/page. Although, the routes are going fine. It's just that the JS file won't get loaded that I need for expanding the menu items - As described in my post. For that, I need to manually refresh/reload the page before JS will be loaded, and then I can expand the menu items when I click on the icon.

Comment: So is this js file call is kept in the component

Comment: It's called in the 'index' file, so it should be there. There's no error or anything like that. If I add a log line in that JS file, then it will only be called when I'm on the login page (which is all fine I would say), but when the user logs in, the menu icon isn't clickable (expandable). Only if I reload the whole page again, then it works.

Comment: Try adding that js file in angular.json scripts array

Comment: I've added it there, now I can see it's loaded 2 times in a row, but didn't work. So, then I've removed it from the 'index' page, being loaded one time. But unfortunately, the same issue. It looks like JS is loaded, but it can't be called. Something like that...

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

It seems that custom code (JS) is being called on document ready event. That explains why it's working the only first time. See comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46349639/2318669.

What I've done to solve it:

I declared a variable:

```
declare const openMobileMenu: any;
```

And then I bind it from the component:

```
onMobile() {
  openMobileMenu();
}
```

To the following method in the JS file:

```
function openMobileMenu() {
  $(".horizontal-menu .bottom-navbar").toggleClass("header-toggled");
};
```

Thanks anyway for the support! :)

I appreciate it.